# How to automatically retry voice recognition without dialog prompt?

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

My app uses Google's voice recognition API. I want it to be a handsfree experience, but when it fails to recognize the voice, it prompts the user to try again by clicking on the button in the dialog. How do I avoid this and retry automatically. I understand that I'm supposed to check the resultCode. This what I tried:

```
if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_NO_MATCH){
/* I wasnt' able to retry voice recognition, so instead to check
if I'm able to actually check if resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_NO_MATCH
I tried this */
TextView.setText("No match");

}
```

but that didn't work. The only one's that work are RESULT_CANCELED and RESULT_OK. Please suggest changes or post working code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Only in Jelly Bean you can achieve what you want, in `onActivityResult` you can do an

```
if(resultCode == RecognizerIntent.RESULT_OK)  
// handle result
else
//finish Google voice recognition and start again.
```

For version below JB, onActivityResult is called only if there is a match or the cancel button is pressed.

Comment: You can write a service to achieve continuous voice recognition.

Comment: Could you provide some more info on that please.